# copying date with milliseconds in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, copy, range

I would like to copy the exact date contained in one cell to another cell. I use this command:

```
Range("E" & ii).Value = Range("C" & ii).Value
```

but the date format is missing the milliseconds despite having the column formatted using:

```
Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.0"
```

I get "0" millisecond always in E column despite having a millisecond value in C column.

thanks and regards

Comment: user3371700, this one works `Range("E" & ii).Value = CDec(Range("C" & ii).Value)`

Answer (score 0):

Use this format:

"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.000"

Comment: Yeah, should use `CDec()` as simoco says.